# How to customize whats copied to the drop folder after a successful TFS build?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I have all my projects successfully compiled to `../sources` and I'd like to get just one folder from the hierarchy created and put it in the drop folder.
What is the best way to achieve this? Also, should I clean the sources directory after each build, or does the build server have some kind of retention policy?

Answer (score 0):

the build server's got a retention policy on the drop folder (edit your builddef and have a look), you don't have to do anything with the sources' folder.

if you only want to copy one folder from the drop location, your options include: editing the build xaml, or adding a new msbuild proj to be built with uses a copy task to move files to your drop location. I'd go with the latter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Tfs 2013 default template it has post build parameter which accepts powershell .you can use that.

Or

You may need to add a invokeprocess activity in your tempalate which can run power shell